# Other forums like Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, clone, forums

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What Stack Exchange sites are up?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20291/what-stack-exchange-sites-are-up)
>   [SO Clones?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/so-clones)

There is another forum called startups.com.  It has the same format as Stack Overflow but it's about business.  The fact that there are two forums with the same format leads me to believe that there might be other forums with the same format, but about different subjects.  I think this format is really great.  Are there any other forums that have the same format besides startups.com?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20291/what-stack-exchange-sites-are-up - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/so-clones

Answer (score 3):

Startups.com is actually a [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) website.

You can see a list of all StackExchange websites [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites).

Answer (score 2):

Startups.com is a [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) site, hence the similar look and feel.

As a matter of almost pure pedantics, these sites are not forums - these are Q&A sites. The difference is somewhat subtle, but important to understanding why the sites work the way they do.